# Devices on Konqueror

Tags: devices, konqueror

As it happens in Konqueror 5.0.97 there is no sidebar which was earlier toggled by F9, which is sad, because it was very useful. 
Still, is it possible to view the attached devices (harddrive, usb) as separate links as it was earlier or as it is in Dolphin?
Or maybe it is possible somehow to use an earlier version of Konqueror with the sidebar?
I am using Ubuntu 18.

Thanks you.

Comment: How did you get Konqueror 5.0.97? That's not the version available for Ubuntu 18.04, AFAICT: `Candidate: 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1`. See [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=konqueror&searchon=names).

Comment: @DK Bose Just used the command line - https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-konqueror-5-0-97-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: You're right. I just checked. Konqueror's About page shows the version you mention but `apt policy konqueror` shows what I posted above. Anyway, I stay with Dolphin. I don't have much luck with Konqueror. If you don't get help here, try asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/), or [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/) or [reddit/kubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/).

Comment: Konqueror was discontinued as file browser. ... Konqueror-5 is an Internet browser only.